# Python3 Pyserial

Tags: python3

Hi, I am currently using python 3.6. I have already made several applications using pyserial and python 2.7. I want to do the same with Python 3.6. not only doesn't it give any error but also there is no data .

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1',9600)
ser.write('\nMerhaba Lutfen [y] veya [n] karakterlerinden birini tuslayiniz: 
')
print ("Seri Haberlesme basliyor\n")

while 1:
    karakter=ser.read()

    if karakter == 'y':
            print ("\nYes denildi\n")
            ser.write( '\n[y] karakterini tusladiniz\n')
    elif karakter == "n":
            print ("\nNo denildi\n")
            ser.write('\n[n] karakterini tusladiniz \n')


    else:
            print ("\nbelirlenemeyen bir karakter girisi\n")
            ser.write('\nGirilen karakter =>')
            ser.write(karakter)
            ser.write('\nKarakter belirlenemedigi icin cevap alinmadi. [y]veya [n] karakterlerinden birini girin\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: it doesn't give any error but there is no data flow(communication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flushing the input buffer before any read or write commands.

```
ser.flushInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem. i have used ser.flush but even if i haven't used it, the program would work. I thought it would be well to clear the input buffer. I have made some additions to the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1',9600)
ser.flushInput( )
ser.write(b'\nMerhaba Lutfen [y] veya [n] karakterlerinden birini tuslayiniz: ')
print ("Seri Haberlesme basliyor\n")

while 1:
    ser.flushInput()
    karakter=ser.read().decode()
    if karakter ==       'y':
            print ("\nYes denildi\n")
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.write( b'\n[y] karakterini tusladiniz\n')
    elif karakter == "n":
            print ("\nNo denildi\n")
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.write(b'\n[n] karakterini tusladiniz \n')
    else:
            print ("\nbelirlenemeyen bir karakter girisi\n")
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.write(b'\nGirilen karakter =>')
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.write(karakter.encode())
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.write(b'\nKarakter belirlenemedigi icin cevap alinmadi. [y]veya [n] karakterlerinden birini girin\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```